# Yes and no while loop not validating if incorrect string is entered in C

Tags: c

When correct option is selected the program loops fine but if the user selects a wrong choice the program keeps looping at the wrong answer. I tried many other solutions but none seem to be working.________________________________________________________________________________________

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define correct 1
#define incorrect 0

int main(void)
{
    int  y, flags = incorrect;
    size_t r = 0;
    char s ='y';
    int v;  
    char courses[5][100];       
            
    char list_courses[5][100] = {"CSE1100", 
                                "CSE1101",
                                "CSE1102", 
                                "ITE1100",
                                "ITE1101"};
            
            
    do{
        printf("Enter Courses :\n Courses available: \n CSE1100 \n CSE1101 \n ITE1100\n ITE1101\n");
        scanf("%s", courses[r]);
        getchar(); 
        r++;
        
        for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
        {
            y = strcmp(&list_courses[i][0],courses[i]);
            if(y == 0)
            {
                flags = correct;
            }        
        }   
        while(flags != correct)
        {
                
            for(size_t p = 0; p <r ; p++)
            {
                printf("%s incorrect choose from list of courses \n CSE1100 \n CSE1101 \n ITE1100\n ITE1101\n", courses[p]);
                printf("try again!:\n", courses[p]);   

                scanf("%s", courses[p]);
                getchar();   
            }
        }       
        for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
        {
            y = strcmp(&list_courses[i][0],courses[i]);
            if(y == 0)
            {
                flags = correct;
            }
        }
            
        printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n) \n"); 
        s = getchar();
    }while(s == 'y');
}
```

Comment: If your code used any sort of consistent formatting I'd read it, but not this.

Comment: Isnt it easier?

Comment: Note that the courses in your `printf` message do not correspond completely with the list of courses in the `list_courses` array.

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for(size_t p = 0; p <r ; p++)` seems redundant, as it does not seem appropriate to print the error message several times.

The lines

```
scanf( "%s", courses[r] );
getchar();
```

will not work if the user enters more than one word of input. In that case, the `getchar` function call will not consume the newline character from the input stream. Also, it is always possible that `scanf` will fail, so you should always check the return value of that function. Additionally, you should always restrict the number of characters written to the buffer, otherwise, if the user enters too much data, this will cause a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), and your program may crash. Therefore, is better to use the following code:

```
int c;

if ( scanf( "%99s", courses[r] ) != 1 )
{
    //TODO: handle error
}
do
{
    c = getchar();

} while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );
```

Also, instead of using

```
#define correct 1
#define incorrect 0
```

and using these values with a variable named `flags`, it would seem easier to use the data type `bool` and introduce a variable `input_valid`, which defaults to `false`. You must `#include <stdbool.h>` in order to use this data type.

Also, if the user enters a wrong value, you are duplicating most of the input code. This is unnecessary. You should instead repeat the loop iteration.

Solving the problem would be easier if you first only attempt to read a single course from the user:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_COURSES 5

int main(void)
{
    bool input_valid = false;

    const char * const list_courses[NUM_COURSES] = {
        "CSE1100",
        "CSE1101",
        "CSE1102",
        "ITE1100",
        "ITE1101"
    };

    while ( !input_valid )
    {
        char input[100];
        int c;

        //prompt user for input
        printf(
            "Courses available:\n"
            " CSE1100\n"
            " CSE1101\n"
            " CSE1102\n"
            " ITE1100\n"
            " ITE1101\n"
            "\n"
            "Enter Course: "
        );

        //attempt to read one word of user input
        if ( scanf( "%99s", input ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "unexpected input failure!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //discard remainder of input line
        do
        {
            c = getchar();

        } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );

        //determine whether course entered was valid or not
        for( int i = 0; i < NUM_COURSES; i++ )
        {
            if ( strcmp(input, list_courses[i] ) == 0)
            {
                input_valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //if invalid, print error message
        if ( !input_valid )
            printf( "Invalid choice! Try again.\n\n" );
    }

    printf( "Input was valid.\n" );
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1103
Invalid choice! Try again.

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1102
Input was valid.
```

If you want the user to be able to enter multiple courses, then you will need an additional outer loop and you will need a place to store all the courses that the user has selected. In your code, you have allocated 100 bytes for storing every course. However, this is rather wasteful, as all you have to remember is an index between `0` and `4`, because there are only 5 courses in the array `list_courses`. You only need a single byte to store such a small number, so a `char` would be sufficient. But let's not be too thrifty and use an `int` instead (which is 4 bytes on most common platforms):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_COURSES 5

int main(void)
{
    int selected_courses[NUM_COURSES];
    int num_selected_courses = 0;
    int c;

    const char * const list_courses[NUM_COURSES] = {
        "CSE1100",
        "CSE1101",
        "CSE1102",
        "ITE1100",
        "ITE1101"
    };

    do
    {
        bool input_valid = false;
        int selected_course;
        int d;

        while ( !input_valid )
        {
            char input[100];

            //prompt user for input
            printf(
                "Courses available:\n"
                " CSE1100\n"
                " CSE1101\n"
                " CSE1102\n"
                " ITE1100\n"
                " ITE1101\n"
                "\n"
                "Enter Course: "
            );

            //attempt to read one word of user input
            if ( scanf( "%99s", input ) != 1 )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "unexpected input failure!\n" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //discard remainder of input line
            do
            {
                d = getchar();

            } while ( d != '\n' && d != EOF );

            //determine whether course entered was valid or not
            for( int i = 0; i < NUM_COURSES; i++ )
            {
                if ( strcmp(input, list_courses[i] ) == 0)
                {
                    input_valid = true;
                    selected_course = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //if invalid, print error message
            if ( !input_valid )
                printf( "Invalid choice! Try again.\n\n" );
        }

        //input was valid, so add course
        selected_courses[num_selected_courses] = selected_course;
        num_selected_courses++;

        //if we have already reached the maximum number of
        //courses, then don't ask again
        if ( num_selected_courses == NUM_COURSES )
            break;

        //ask user whether he wants to add another course
        printf("Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)\n"); 
        c = d = getchar();

        //add spacing
        printf( "\n" );

        //discard remainder of input line
        while ( d != '\n' && d != EOF )
            d = getchar();

    } while ( c == 'y' );

    printf( "You have selected the following courses:\n" );

    //print courses selected by user
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_selected_courses; i++ )
        printf( "%s\n", list_courses[selected_courses[i]] );
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1101
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
y

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: ITE1102
Invalid choice! Try again.

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: ITE1100
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
y

Courses available:
 CSE1100
 CSE1101
 CSE1102
 ITE1100
 ITE1101

Enter Course: CSE1102
Would you like to enter another course? (y or n)
n

You have selected the following courses:
CSE1101
ITE1100
CSE1102
```

Note that this solution is not perfect, because it allows the user to select the same course twice. If you want, you can add an additional check to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks! How would you incorporate a yes no loop to keep asking the user to enter more courses?

Comment: @Link123: I have now added a second program which provides the full solution, as well as an explanation of how it works.

Comment: How would you print the selected courses in another void?

Comment: How would you add the selected courses to an empty array?

Comment: @Link123: In one of your previous comments, you wrote: `"How would you print the selected courses in another void?"` -- I don't understand what you mean with "in another void"? Are you talking about using a `void *`, i.e. a pointer to void?

Comment: @Link123: In one of your previous comments, you wrote: `"How would you add the selected courses to an empty array?"` -- The array `int selected_courses[NUM_COURSES];` is initially empty. So I am already adding the selected courses to an empty array.

Comment: if i added the array to struct like `struct students{ selected_courses[NUM_COURSES];` it wouldnt work as per normal

Comment: Im trying to make a student database and the courses need to be stored in the stuct for each individual student

Comment: @Link123: You must define your struct like this: `struct student { int selected_courses[NUM_COURSES]; int num_selected_courses; };` That way, the `num_selected_courses` member will contain the number of courses that the user has selected, and the `selected_courses` array will contain the actual data, i.e. the  numbers or IDs of the course (which are indexes into the `list_courses` array).